# Keep variable "names" and "variable.labels" attr after subseting a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, import, subset

I imported a .sav file, but after subsetting the original dataframe I loose the attribute "variable.labels" and I end up only seeing the variable codes, which makes it a bit tougher to read the variables in View()

I found the copy_labels() function but it doesn't keep the "variable.labels"
Here is sample of my code:

```
library(foreign)
with BD_data<-read.spss("file.sav", to.data.frame = TRUE) 

# Read variables to include in subset
Vect.analisis <- read_csv("D:/Mis Documentos/Vectors.csv")

# Subset Q5
Q5.1.vect<-Vect.analisis[!is.na(Vect.analisis$Variables_5.1),c("Variables_5.1")]
Q5.1.vect<-as.vector(Q5.1.vect$Variables_5.1)
Q5.1<-subset(BD_Higiene, select = c("CONTROL_CUOTA",Q5.1.vect))

Q5.1<-copy_labels(BD_Higiene,Q5.1,)
str(Q5.1)

# $ P5v4c_20     : Factor w/ 2 levels "No seleccionado",..: NA 1 1 1 1 1 2 NA NA 1 ...
# $ P5v4c_21     : Factor w/ 2 levels "No seleccionado",..: NA 2 2 1 2 1 1 NA NA 2 ...
# $ P5v4c_22     : Factor w/ 2 levels "No seleccionado",..: NA 2 1 2 1 2 2 NA NA 1 ...
# $ P5v4c_23     : Factor w/ 2 levels "No seleccionado",..: NA 1 1 1 1 2 1 NA NA 1 ...
#  [list output truncated]
```

But when I do the following code the "variable.names" seem to be there, howver in View() I cannot see them:

```
Q5.1 %>% copy_labels(BD_Higiene) %>% str()

#  [list output truncated]
# - attr(*, "variable.labels")= Named chr  "id" "[owid]" "[panelistid]" "state" ...
#  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "id" "URLPARAMETERS_owid" "URLPARAMETERS_panelistid" "STATE" ...
# - attr(*, "codepage")= int 65001

View(BD_Higiene)
#vs
View(Q5.1)
```

[image]

vs

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend the `haven` package to read in spss files. I usually don't have problems with labels then. Not sure if the `subset` function you are using kills the labels, but you might want to look at the `tidyverse` approach of things, especially the `filter` function in your case. Labels are perfectly kept there.